# What is android default color for disabled text in edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textcolor

I want to set hint color in `EditText` as disabled text color. So I am using `android:textColorHint` attribute. But I don't know how to do that:

```
android:textColorHint="@android:color/???"     // what should I select?
//OR
android:textColorHint="?android:attr/???"      // what should I select?
```

**Edit:** I can define the same color in values but I want to reference it to handle future changes.

Comment: I know that its black with a lowered opacity, but for the sake of it I screenshot it and used the color picker tool in Photoshop and the shade seems to be #bdbdbd.

Answer (score 10):

You can find answer in documentation
https://material.google.com/style/color.html#color-text-background-colors

> For dark text on light backgrounds, apply the following opacity
>   levels:
>
> The most important text has an opacity of 87%.
>  Secondary text,
>   which is lower in the visual hierarchy, has an opacity of 54%.
>   Text hints (like those in text fields and labels) and disabled text
>   have even lower visual prominence with an opacity of 38%.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the colour in disabled state is actually not a different colour (like grey), but the default colour (e.g. black) with a lowered opacity.

Comment: This is black with 38% opacity: `<color name="android_default_disabled">#61000000</color>` it worked fine for me for disabled hint text color

Comment: The design docs do say use alpha, but that incurs a performance penalty as mentioned in the [Reduce Overdraw](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/overdraw#rt) doc. Instead, it recommends finding the color without using transparency.

Answer (score 5):

**Hello Misagh, You can get the hint color using following ways :**

```
 1. final ColorStateList colors = editText.getHintTextColors();
     editText.setTextColor(colors);`
```

2. Color code is : #808080 (R-128, G-128, B-128)

**You can go through this documantation :** http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getHintTextColors%28%29

Please let me know , If having any problem.

Comment: Your solution in helpful, but actually not the answer. Because I want to change hint color to disable color, not changing disable color to hint color. However I am voting it up. Thanks.